# Space under navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I can't remove the unnecessary space under the second navigation bar. Here goes the html and css of that portion.I have also added the picture to show how it looks like in this state.
Css part:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #04476b;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    border-radius: 0;

}

.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #fa897f !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: #04476b !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Html part:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="height: 80px; background-color: lightcoral">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar2">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#doctor">Doctor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#doctorlist">Doctor List</a></li>
                <li><a href="#appointment" onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Appointment</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Doctor..">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
                </div>
            </form>
            </ul>


        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="id03" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-dialog" action="">
            <div class="modal-content animate">
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='none'" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                    <img src="app.png" style="height: auto" width="auto" alt="Avatar" >
                </div>

                <div class="container2">
                    <label><b>Mail ID</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name= "mailID" id="mailID" required>
                    <p id="mailIdErr"></p>

                    <label><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>
                    <p id="pswErr"></p>

                    <button id ="submit" type="submit" style="height: auto" width="auto" onclick="globalAppointment()">Submit</button>
                    <p id="loginErr"></p>
                    <!--<button type="submit" style="height: auto" width="auto" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'
                     "href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal">Make Health Card</button>-->
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn"data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

[image: It looks something like this.]

Comment: Its seems to be fixed!

Comment: Not at all. Look carefully Home, Doctor, Logout these portions are a little bit upward though it was supposed to be in the middle position. It doesn't seem good.

Comment: I created a fiddle with the `css` and `html` you gave us, and there is no problem at all see https://jsfiddle.net/y01he4r4/. So give more information and/or create a fiddle with the actual problem being visualised ..

Comment: maybe problem is not in navigation but things below it

Comment: I don't understand. It's showing perfect in the fiddle! But i don't get the same result when i run it in browser.